# One line if-condition-assignment in AutoHotkey

Tags: operators, autohotkey, variable-assignment, assignment-operator, short-circuiting

In JavaScript, we could use the following one-liner:

```js
const condition = true

let foo

condition && (foo = 'foo') //  one-liner

console.log(foo) // foo
```

I tried this in AHK:

```
condition := true

condition && (foo := "foo")

MsgBox % foo
```

However, the interpreter throws:

[image]

I had to change the above code to the following to prompt "foo":

```
condition := true

;  three lines
if (condition) {
  foo := "foo"
}

MsgBox % foo
```

How to do this type of assignment in one line in AHK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the [ternary operator (?:)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#ternary) to achieve this, unlike in JavaScript, we can omit the losing branch in AutoHotkey:

```
condition := true

condition ? foo := "foo"

MsgBox % foo
```

Also, quote from [0x464e](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813732):

> Note that you can only omit the losing branch if you're not trying to get the evaluation result of the whole ternary, e.g. `var1 := TrueCondition ? "hello"` does not work. The variable `var1` doesn't get any value set to it.