# Why `PrevActiveClass ? WinActivate ahk_class %PrevActiveClass%` is not working?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, operators, autohotkey, conditional-operator

`PrevActiveClass` is assigned a value, the following code won't activate `PrevActiveClass` (although [the syntax works for assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69149349/7881859)):

```
PrevActiveClass ? WinActivate ahk_class %PrevActiveClass%
```

But the following will activate `PrevActiveClass`:

```
if (PrevActiveClass) {
  WinActivate ahk_class %PrevActiveClass%
}
```

Why is the first snippet not working, and how to implement the same logic in one line of code?

Comment: The ternary operator only works in expressions, not in commands. WinActivate is a command.

Comment: As in the example in 0x464e's answer,  you can make a function out of (a) command(s). Functions are expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using a ternary, you're in an expression.

Legacy commands can only be used when in a legacy statement, so more clearly said, only at the start of a new line <sub><sup>(under normal circumstances)</sup></sub>.

What you're trying to do right now, is concatenate three variables together <sub><sup>(and discard the result)</sup></sub> named `WinActivate`, `ahk_class` and a dynamic variable named `PrevActiveClass`.

> how to implement the same logic in one line of code?

You can't.

The best you can do is two lines:

```
if (PrevActiveClass)
  WinActivate, % "ahk_class " PrevActiveClass
```

<sub><sup>(I switched to using an expression, would've worked in the legacy syntax as well, but ew, legacy syntax)</sup></sub>

Technically you could, of course, do this:

```
WinActivate, % PrevActiveClass ? "ahk_class " PrevActiveClass : "NonExistentWindow"
```

But that would be a really stupid design.

Also, you could define your own function for activating a window and then call that in your expression:

```
PrevActiveClass ? WinActivateFunc("ahk_class " PrevActiveClass)

WinActivateFunc(WinTitle := "", WinText := "", ExcludeTitle := "", ExcludeText := "")
{
  WinActivate, % WinTitle, % WinText, % ExcludeTitle, % ExcludeText
}
```

Some people actually do this so they can use legacy commands inline.

I know there are some libraries people have made as well which offer functions like that for every(?) legacy command.

You should be able to find one from probably the AHK forums.

---

Also, I guess AHKv2 deserves a mention here since there simply is no legacy syntax in v2. This problem is non-existent there.

Comment: _"Legacy commands can only be used when in a legacy statement"_, you mean `WinActivate` is a legacy command? But AHK v2 [has it](https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm) too, and what is a legacy statement?

Comment: Well I simply mean that it hasn't been superseded by a modern function. An example of this would be for example the legacy command [`IfWinExist`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfWinExist.htm) being superseded by the modern function [`WinExist()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinExist.htm). So, since `WinActivate` is a legacy command, as opposed to be a modern function, it can not be used in an expression. It has be at the start of a new line.

Comment: And about that AHKv2 note, yes it's still there, but legacy isn't a thing in v2, in v2 you'd use it like `WinActivate("ahk_exe notepad.exe")` (although omitting `( )` is also allowed). And because there is no legacy syntax, everything is in expression syntax, you could also use it inline like this just fine `true ? WinActivate("ahk_exe notepad.exe") : ""`.